# An asynchronous logger

Tags: asynchronous, rust, logging

I've written a simple asynchronous logger ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a1d177bd924eb759615cc1b01f9aefa5)):

```
mod logger {

    use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
    use time::now;

    pub type LogError = std::sync::mpsc::SendError<String>;

    /// Runs a function that can logs asynchronously.
    pub fn log<F, T>(f: F) -> T
    where
        F: FnOnce(Logger) -> T,
    {
        let (sender, receiver) = channel();
        let handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {
            while let Ok(msg) = receiver.recv() {
                println!("{}", msg);
            }
            println!("LOG FINISHED");
        });
        let result = f(Logger { sender });

        handle.join().unwrap(); // Error handling?

        result
    }

    /// The actual logger.
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct Logger {
        sender: Sender<String>,
    }

    impl Logger {
        /// Logs an information.
        pub fn info(&self, s: impl std::fmt::Display) -> Result<(), LogError> {
            let s = format!("[{}] [INFO ] {}", now().rfc3339(), s);

            self.sender.send(s)
        }

        /// Logs an error.
        pub fn error(&self, s: impl std::fmt::Display) -> Result<(), LogError> {
            let s = format!("[{}] [ERROR] {}", now().rfc3339(), s);

            self.sender.send(s)
        }
    }

}

// Demontration:
fn main() -> Result<(), logger::LogError> {
    logger::log(|logger| {
        logger.info("Hello world")?;

        // Cloning without overhead:
        logger.clone().error("Oops, error")
    })
}
```

The concept is simple: I spawn a thread with a receiver, and the logger sends the text to it.

To make this work, I was forced to use a callback to correctly join the thread when the user's code is done. Is there a better/prettier way to do that?

And also, is that pattern efficient? I know that I can buffer the lines inside the spawned thread, but I am talking about the whole pattern.

Comment: It might be an idea to use `std::sync::mpsc::sync_channel` instead for something like this. `sync_channel`, unlike `channel`, guarantees that the order out will be the same as the order in... but it's also slightly more complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to use a runtime struct instead of a closure. `Logger` needs to borrow the runtime, and it must implement `Drop` so that `Runtime::drop` is not called before `Logger::drop`.

```
mod logger {

    use std::marker::PhantomData;
    use std::sync::mpsc::{channel, Sender};
    use std::thread::JoinHandle;
    use time::now;

    pub type LogError = std::sync::mpsc::SendError<String>;

    pub struct Runtime {
        sender: Option<Sender<String>>,
        thread_handle: Option<JoinHandle<()>>,
    }

    impl Runtime {
        pub fn new() -> Self {
            let (sender, receiver) = channel();
            let thread_handle = std::thread::spawn(move || {
                while let Ok(msg) = receiver.recv() {
                    println!("{}", msg);
                }
                println!("LOG FINISHED");
            });

            Runtime {
                sender: Some(sender),
                thread_handle: Some(thread_handle),
            }
        }

        pub fn logger(&self) -> Logger {
            Logger {
                sender: self.sender.clone().unwrap(),
                _marker: PhantomData,
            }
        }
    }

    impl Drop for Runtime {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            // Removes the last sender alive, so that the thread quits.
            let _ = self.sender.take();

            if let Some(handle) = self.thread_handle.take() {
                if let Err(e) = handle.join() {
                    eprintln!("Error while exiting the logger manager: {:?}", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /// The actual logger.
    #[derive(Clone)]
    pub struct Logger<'a> {
        sender: Sender<String>,
        _marker: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
    }

    impl Logger<'_> {
        /// Logs an information.
        pub fn info(&self, s: impl std::fmt::Display) -> Result<(), LogError> {
            let s = format!("[{}] [INFO ] {}", now().rfc3339(), s);

            self.sender.send(s)
        }

        /// Logs an error.
        pub fn error(&self, s: impl std::fmt::Display) -> Result<(), LogError> {
            let s = format!("[{}] [ERROR] {}", now().rfc3339(), s);

            self.sender.send(s)
        }
    }

    impl Drop for Logger<'_> {
        fn drop(&mut self) {
            // The non-trivial drop prevents the logger to outlives the manager.
        }
    }
}

// Demontration:
fn main() -> Result<(), logger::LogError> {
    let log_manager = logger::Runtime::new();
    let logger = log_manager.logger();

    logger.info("Hello world")?;
    // Cloning without overhead:
    logger.clone().error("Oops, error")?;

    Ok(())
}
```

If one try to make a logger outlive the runtime, it will not compile:

```
fn main() -> Result<(), logger::LogError> {
    let log_manager = logger::Runtime::new();
    let logger = log_manager.logger();

    logger.clone().info("Hello world")
}
```

Gives:

```
error[E0597]: `log_manager` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:85:18
   |
85 |     let logger = log_manager.logger();
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
86 | 
87 |     logger.clone().info("Hello world")
   |     -------------- a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
88 | }
   | -
   | |
   | `log_manager` dropped here while still borrowed
   | ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the `Drop` code for type `logger::Logger`
   |
   = note: The temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block. Consider forcing this temporary to be dropped sooner, before the block's local variables are dropped. For example, you could save the expression's value in a new local variable `x` and then make `x` be the expression at the end of the block.
```